# how can I make a HSS blade thinner?

Tags: tools, hand-tools

I have a HSS blade whose size is 200mmx30mmx3mm. For some particular reason, I need to make it thinner to 2mm-2.5mm.

Is there any tool or approach that I can use to archive this without too much effort?

Comment: A surface grinder. Standard machine shop tool. Since you probably don't have one, hire someone who does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realistically you just need to buy a thinner one.  I very much doubt you would be able to plane it down yourself to the precision needed.